# SQL find similar content

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `ITEMS` and column `URL`. All I need is in `items.url` to find similar rows:

Example of two similar rows:

```
ITEM_ID  |    URL    
1        | www.google.com/test1/test2/test3.php       
2        | www.yahoo.com/test1/test2/test3.php
3        | www.google.com/test5.php
4        | www.facebook.com/test5.php
```

As you can see the URL is similar JUST with different domains.

My query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS
WHERE URL LIKE `%google.com%`...
AND `here code probably` ???
```

My query should return me ITEM_ID 2 and 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by the substring starting from the '/' character, and take the max ID in the group. Using postgresql syntax, it should look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ITEMS t
 WHERE t.item_id IN (SELECT MAX(s.item_d)
                       FROM ITEMS s
                      GROUP BY SUBSTRING(s.url FROM POSITION('/' IN s.url)))
 ORDER BY t.item_id;
```

**Update:** if you want only google domains, which have similar rows on different domains, you could use a filter EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ITEMS t
 WHERE t.url LIKE 'www.google.com%'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM ITEMS s
                WHERE s.url NOT LIKE 'www.google.com%'
                  AND SUBSTRING(t.url FROM POSITION('/' IN t.url)) =
                      SUBSTRING(s.url FROM POSITION('/' IN s.url)));
```

Comment: The query looks ok. The only thing I want is instead of default MAX(item_id) I need to have the the record that contains item.url LIKE '%google%'. All results should have google domain